# Save execute procedure results into a var in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure that executes another procedure and I need to save the results into a variable.

How can I do that?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetDetailsByUserId
    @userId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        usr.FirstName, usr.LastName, usr.UserName, usr.Email
    FROM 
        [User] usr
    WHERE   
        usr.UserID = @userId

    EXEC sp_GenerateRandomPass @userId // this result need to be inside a var
END
```

I am a beginner and need help.

Thank you.

Comment: What you meant by `var`.  Is `sp_GenerateRandomPass` procedure returning table or what?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a **Table** or you can use a **Temp Table**:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetDetailsByUserId
  @userId int
  AS
  BEGIN
  SELECT usr.FirstName, usr.LastName, usr.UserName, usr.Email
  FROM [User] usr
  WHERE usr.UserID = @userId

  declare @tbl table (the columns should be compatible with the result columns)

  insert into @tbl
  exec sp_GenerateRandomPass @userId // this result need to be inside a var

END
```

with **temptable** you can do:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GetDetailsByUserId
  @userId int
  AS
  BEGIN
  SELECT usr.FirstName, usr.LastName, usr.UserName, usr.Email
  FROM [User] usr
  WHERE usr.UserID = @userId

  create table #tempTable(the columns should be compatible with the result columns)

  insert into  #tempTable
  exec sp_GenerateRandomPass @userId // this result need to be inside a var

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the procedure? Having output parameters would probably be best, assuming the select always returns just one row.

```
exec sp_GenerateRandomPass @userId, @password output
```

output parameters work this way:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_GenerateRandomPass
@userId int,
@password varchar (100) output
AS
BEGIN
    -- Magic happens
    set @password = 'xxxx'
END
```

Other option is to change GenerateRandomPass to be a scalar function, you can assign value from it to a variable directly in your procedure

Also, please do not prefix your procedures with "sp_", it's intended for built in procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `sp_GenerateRandomPass` , Store result of query within this stored procedure to `temptable`. Find more about [temptable](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables).

Temp table will be accessible among stored procedures. So you can use that in `sp_GetDetailsByUserId`